# Firebase push notification sent twice

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an app that has firebase notifications, i followed through the firebase tutorial guides in order to how to send and receive notifications but I'm receiving 2 notifications on other devices instead of receiving 1 and receiving a notification from the sent device although that device shouldn't receive the notification that was sent from it

I saw other questions regarding uploading notifications twice but it didn't work for me

P.S: the notification is sent from a custom dialog that has title edit text and body edit text

here is the manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I'm compiling these in the gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0'
```

Here's the code for the custom dialog:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_send_notification, null);
        builder.setView(view)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.send), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        EditText editMessage = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.notification_message);
                        EditText editTitle = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.notification_title);
                        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                        int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                        int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
                        int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        String message = editMessage.getText().toString().replace(' ', '_');
                        String title = editTitle.getText().toString().replace(' ', '_');

                        boolean cancel = false;
                        View focusView = null;

                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
                            editMessage.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
                            focusView = editMessage;
                            cancel = true;
                        }

                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
                            editTitle.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
                            focusView = editTitle;
                            cancel = true;
                        }

                        if (cancel)
                            focusView.requestFocus();
                        else {
                            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(NotificationsActivity.this);
                            String url = "https://mysite.here/send_push.php?" +
                                    "message=" + message +
                                    "&title=" + title +
                                    "&day=" + day +
                                    "&month=" + month +
                                    "&year=" + year;
                            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    Log.d("send push response", response);
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    error.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            });
                            queue.add(request);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.button_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                });
        sendNotificationDialog = builder.create();
```

here is the firebaseMessagingService:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void sendNotification(String messageTitle, String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_spe_bau)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 , notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

here is the firebaseInstanceIDService:

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d("firebase ID", refreshedToken);
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    String url = "https://mysite.here/insertFCM_ID.php?fcmID=" + token;
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("fcm response", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
}
```

send_push.php code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json, charset=UTF-8");
require('db.php');

$db = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password) or die('Could not connect');
mysqli_select_db($db, $db_name) or die('');
$message    = $_GET['message'];
$title      = $_GET['title'];
$day        = $_GET['day'];
$month      = $_GET['month'];
$year       = $_GET['year'];

$server_key = "somekey";
$sql        = 'select fcm_token from fcm_info';
$result     = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or print("Error");
$key        = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $key[] = $row;
}

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . $server_key,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$single  = "";

foreach($key as $value) {
    $single  = $value['fcm_token'];

    $fields  = array(
        'to' => $single,
        'notification' => array(
            'title' => str_replace("_", " ", $title),
            'body' => str_replace("_", " ", $message),
            'vibrate' => 1,
            'sound' => 1
        )
    );
    $payload = json_encode($fields);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
}

mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO notifications (title, body, day, month, year) VALUES ('$title', '$message', '$day', '$month', '$year')");

mysqli_close($db);
echo $result;
?>
```

i tried a lot of ways in order to find where the problem is but i couldn't know what it is

if more information is needed i will re-edit this to add those required information

Comment: Hi. Can you post your `send_push.php` (remove the sensitive details)? Also, from your server, are you also receiving double responses after sending the message?

Comment: do you mean if the notification is registered twice in my database? if yes then yeah it is

Comment: Hi. Nope. What I was referring to was from your sending the message from your server, you receive a response from the FCM server (probably a `200 OK` response), do you receive it twice too?

Comment: well I should be getting a response because the system is also platformed on the iOS too and the iOS version also receives 2 notifications

Answer (score 0):

Make comment line in your onMessageReceived event:

```
//sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
```

Try again after you make this change in your firebaseInstanceIDService class. It should be ok.
If you want to use only Downstream messages, you need to decide your message type. Data messages or notifications. You also need to manage 3 situations of your app on the device: Foreground, Background and Killed. Data messages are always trigger onMessageReceived event on your Service. This is different when you send notification message. I suggest you sending Data messages as Post requests. You don't have any problem now. You are sending Post request to 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' URL via Volley and you are sending a notification. Then your service is receiving your notification and create another one. It is very normal to receive 2 notifications, because your code is generating 2 notification. I told you make comment line and test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the message-id in a variable then when a new message received twice, the first message-id will be saved in this variable and when it called twice the second time you will check if exists in your variable or not .. for example

```
String savedMessageId  = "";

 public void setupFCM() {

 if (savedMessageId != remoteMessage.messageId)
        savedMessageId  = remoteMessage.messageId;
      else
        return;


     // your code ...
  }
```